# Dynamically set Type when calling constructor with predefined types

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently struggling to create a public attribute but the type is defined when constructor is called.

This is my code now:

```
public class clsHtml: IDisposable
{

    public enum Types { Section, Input, File, Radio, Checkbox, Select };

    public TYPE HERE element;

    public clsHtml(Types type)
    {
        CreateElement(type);
    }

    private void CreateElement(Types type)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case Types.Input:
                element = new HtmlInputText();
                break;

            case Types.File:
                element = new HtmlInputFile();
                break;

            case Types.Radio:
                element = new HtmlInputRadioButton();
                break;

            case Types.Checkbox:
                element = new HtmlInputCheckBox();
                break;

            case Types.Select:
                element = new HtmlSelect();
                break;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter html = new HtmlTextWriter(writer);

        element.RenderControl(html);

        return writer.ToString();
    }
}
```

Where it says `TYPE HERE`, should I use `dynamic` or `object` or what ? I am going to access it from outside (public), I just have a simple `ToString()` method that will parse it with `StringWriter` and `HtmlTextWriter` to get it as HTML String.

I am using ASP.NET (not MVC) so, is it a performance matter what I choose ? If I choose `object` type, can I still access the methods that are on each object inside the `switch` ?

I want to do a `new` on this class defining the type of element it will create, so I can use some methods of the selected class to set things. For example, if I choose `HtmlInputRadioButton` I can use `.Checked` but I will use this element in other class, for setting attributes depending which element you created. Am I clear ?

---

One possible solution is to create variables with each type, but use a property to see which one is not null and get that one but this is not an elegant solution.

---

Other solution is to use Generics using `where T : HtmlControls, new()` but I want the user to not know that, I want him to only write `new(Types.WHICH ONE TO USE)`.

Thanks all !!!

Comment: how about using the base class `HtmlControl` or something similar as the return type and cast it to the right type on the calling code? wouldn't that work for you?

Comment: I don't know what are you saying, I know nearly nothing about casting :S I think I saw it one time... can you explain more please ?

Comment: Sure. here is a basic sample, as am not sure what you mean by the user **shouldn't** know. `var htmlEle= new clsHtml(Types Radio)` now on the calling code, try `htmlEle.getType()` which will return `HtmlInputRadioButton ` and cast it back to that type to use the methods that is inherent to that type.  meaning `var radioBtn= (HtmlInputRadioButton)htmlEle;` then `radioBtn.Checked`

Comment: This works only if you KNOW what type it was or is it supposed to be. See my type-sniffing comments below.

Comment: So, both @JS_GodBlessAll and @Hristo Yaknov if I do `public HtmlControl element;` then in the switch I create any element, and then when I do `(REAL TYPE CREATED BEFORE ON SWITCH)clsHTML.element.ANY METHOD OF THAT TYPE` will work, right ? I surely have to know which is the real type but I can know because the methods that will use this are the ones creating this elements, so they know which type they are using.

Comment: `((REAL TYPE CREATED IN SWITCH)clsHTML.element).ANY METHOD OF THAT TYPE`

Comment: It would be a good idea to read a book, a tutorial or follow a course on C# and/or object-oriented programming as otherwise you will surely write poor code that is hard to maintain or not very efficient.

Comment: **You cannot write anything instead of `TYPE HERE`** that would be type-safe, would support IntelliSense and allows to access specific members. If you use dynamic, then you don't have IntelliSense and there will be not check until run-time that the property do exist. If you use `object` then you only have access to a few standard methods. If you use `HtmlControl`, you still have to check the type every time you need to do specific operations. Using an `Enum` in this case serve no useful purpose. If you really want that kind of code, then use the solution with generic class `clsHtml<t>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public enum Types { Section, Input, File, Radio, Checkbox, Select };

// Why did you decide it to be IDisposable? What are you going to dispose?
public class clsHtml: IDisposable
{
    public HtmlControl element { get; private set; }

    public clsHtml(Types type)
    {
        this.CreateElement(type);
    }

    private void CreateElement(Types type)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case Types.Input:
                this.element = new HtmlInputText();
                break;

            case Types.File:
                this.element = new HtmlInputFile();
                break;

            case Types.Radio:
                this.element = new HtmlInputRadioButton();
                break;

            case Types.Checkbox:
                this.element = new HtmlInputCheckBox();
                break;

            case Types.Select:
                this.element = new HtmlSelect();
                break;

            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException(type.ToString() + " not yet supported!");
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter html = new HtmlTextWriter(writer);

        this.element.RenderControl(html);

        return writer.ToString();
    }
}

var clsHtml = new clsHtml(Types.Input);

// the following part sucks, but you don't want to use generics
if (clsHtml.element is HtmlInputText)
{
  HtmlInputText elementAsHtmlInputText = clsHtml.element as HtmlInputText;
}
else if ( ...)
...
```

Comment: I thought so, but will I be able to acess any method that is in the class, not in the inherited one ? If I create `HtmlInputText` but I use `private HtmlControl element;` will I be able to access all things that are on `HtmlInputText` ? I cant currently test any code, so this is why I am asking and not testing, anyway this is more a basic thing about C# that I am not used to and you are clearing it for me, thanks !

Comment: Of course not. But you said you just want to do `.ToString()` on it.

Comment: Yes, but I will define some things that each class brings with it, for example in `HtmlInputRadioButton` I can use `.Checked` but if I define `HtmlControl` I will not be able to use that. Am I right ? Should there use `dynamic` ?

Comment: Please expand your code sample in the original question, to illustrate what you are trying to achieve. It is not clear. But generally it seems that you will need the `strategy pattern`. I'll show you how, just update the sample first.

Comment: I updated the code adding only `ToString()` but expanding why I want to do this. I wrongly wrote that the element was `private`; it is `public`, read again after the code. Thank you very much !

Comment: I see. Maybe I misunderstood. Of course you can use the concrete class methods in the `switch` statement. My answer is still valid. In the `switch` do whatever you want to do with the `element = new`. Your `ToString()` will work fine.

Comment: Yes yes, but when I do the `element = new` I have to write what type `element` is, because `element` was declared in the class with `public` visibility, so you can use it outside the class. If I do not define a type or anything that solves that, I cant do the `element = new` with varying types.

Comment: The type is `HtmlControl`! It's like saying `Animal cat = new Cat() { Meows = Meowing.alot  }`.

Comment: If I do that, will I be able to access `Cat()` attributes and methods ? For example, `cat.meow()` that is not on `Animal` or will I have to do `(Cat)cat.meow()` ?

Comment: The question is 'when'. You can do it in the `switch`, before you box it into `HtmlControl`. Once boxed (i.e. when you leave the switch), you no longer explicitly know what the type is (implicitly you can `type sniff` it).

Comment: Can you explain a little more about it or give a link ? I didn't know that.

Comment: `if (animal is Cat) { }` - that's sniffing. But again, I don't understand when you will need to know the exact type. If it's just in the `switch`, you have no issue.

Comment: But I will still not be able to use `Cat` attributes and methods outside `switch` or if I access it because it is public, right ?

Comment: Yes. See my other answer then.

Comment: I think this is the solution. Why use `as` and not directly `(type)`. I know which type it is because a method will choose automatically the `type` (enum) so I will all the time know which type it is. I will read from a Database some columns, example, `ColumnA = input`, so I will use `Type.Input`. Do you get it ?

Comment: If you are really sure what type it is, you can cast it directly, sure. If you aren't, you can test what type it is, as I have shown. Still, even if you are really sure what type it is, it's best to do: `Cat cat = animal as Cat; if (cat != null) { ... }`

Comment: Thank you very much, both @Hristo Yankov and @JS_GodBlessAll. I will test this now and see what happens, but I think is the solution. I am saying that if I say that a variable is base class type, but then I do `(type)` or `as` and I am using the type that is inheriting the base class, it will still have all of its methods and attributes and their data of course, right ? By this I mean: `public class Cat : Animal { meow() method... Animal cat; }` and then `Cat cat = (Cat)Cat.cat;` if I know that `cat` attribute was `Cat` type before but saved in a `Animal` attribute ?

Comment: @P0lT10n **Casting shoud be avoided as much as possible in object oriented programming.** If you code in C#, then you should write the in a way that type safety will be done by the compiler and not work around. Presently, you are trying to bypass any good practice and safety in the language. This will only result in poor code that is hard to maintain and understand. You really should learn more about object oriented programming and writing solid code before writing that kind of code. You should not try to mimic typeless language...

Answer (score 4):

```
public class clsHtml<T>
     where T : HtmlControl, new()
{
    public T element;

    public clsHtml()
    {
        element = new T();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter html = new HtmlTextWriter(writer);

        element.RenderControl(html);

        return writer.ToString();
    }
}
```

How about this?

Comment: I have done that before, but any developer who uses this solution must specify the type, I want them to choose between the `enum` on my code, so it is easier... maybe using generics like this and another class I can accomplish this by sending the enum value selected and with generics create it and return it ? I want to avoid the developers to explicity write the type, so it's easier for them and they can only choose  a predefined type available to choose.

Comment: If I am able to use what I say, the IntelliSense will be really helpfull, thats why.

Comment: I know it exists, but it has all the possible tags and not mine pre-selected tags, and what do you mean with it, to use it where ?

Comment: The IntelliSense also exists, just type `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls`

Comment: It makes sense to define your own enum ONLY if you want to restrict the list of supported types.

Comment: I am trying to do that and add one that is define by me, it will do `new HtmlGenericControl("div");` and it will have some defined properties by me in the code. It is the `Section` value in my enum. Do you get what I mean ?

Comment: OK. There is now way to know the type outside this class, without strong-typing it (as with the Generic I have provided). It seems like you have to go with my other solution, and consumers outside of your class will have to inspect the type of the `element` and do whatever they want with it, after casting.

Comment: Updated my other solution.

Comment: @P0lT10n I think that your idea is wrong... **It is well know in OOP that it is better to use subclasses than switching on types.** So it is best to create object of the appropriate type from the start and declare variables of the appropriate type. Although, at first it seems that it would simplify code, this is quite the contrary as with your solution, you would always have to check the control type and you won't have specific IntelliSense for that actual control.

Comment: I vote for your solution as it would be the best solution that somehow wrap controls as in OP code... but in practice, I think it would be better for OP to use controls directly. His idea would only lead to poor, unmaintainable code.

Comment: @Phil1970 yes, the problem is that my team is doesn't know much about C#... I am making it as simple as possible for them, but if the solution I want to try is really unmaintainable, I will use the Generics as I was using it before...

Comment: @P0lT10n If your team does not know much about C#, then they should follows a formation or two... And if they don't know a lot, I think it would be better that they used ASP.NET without your extra layer as it is very easy to find information on the web for the "standard" way of coding. By the way, if you use only ASP.NET (not MVC), then are you using web forms? If so, I don't see the purpose of doing custom stuff.

Comment: because I never used ASP.NET MVC and they will not evert get a clue about how to use it, but we must use ASP, I would love to use PHP, but well... I cant change it, its a directive from TOP, so... I am trying to make it as simple as possible...